# fastest way to merge two images : server

Tags: php, python, image

[image]I am making e-commerce site where images of product are actually created by merging two or more .png images, and creating a .jpg image from that is my main issue.

1. A product will have four images at different angles
2. I will have to create 4*2 = 8 images by all combinations of two images(if product is created by merging two product)

Problem is that if new product is merge of three then total 4*3=12

Generating these images fast and displaying them as soon as page loads will definitely take time

I want to know what should I use for that:

1. PHP
2. Node.js
3. Python
4. Or something else

or another fastest way of doing so what should i use please guide (i am using php for e-commerce platform)

Below is sample example:
1: Table X with Chair Y
with 4 different angle

```
(transparent png + transparent png) = Combined image (in jpg)

X Horizontal view + Y Horizontal view = Combined image (in jpg)
X Top view + Y Top view = Combined image (in jpg)
X 45 deg view + Y 45 deg view = Combined image (in jpg)
X 90 deg view + Y 90 deg view = Combined image (in jpg)
```

Size of each will be 800px * 800px and about 300-400kb

Comment: How about showing us the starting images and the resulting image(s)? How many images do you have - could you pre-create all the combinations and store them?

Comment: show starting images ?? may be baby image + different backgroudn theme images

Comment: So let's continue using the baby example. Client X visits your website and you have 4 photos of Client X's baby looking from different angles (presumably over a transparent background) and you have 3 different backgrounds and you want to composite each of the 4 views with each of the 3 backgrounds and produce 12 images. Correct? What size are your images, i.e. 2000 pixels by 1200 pixels, and what size in kB, and are they PNGs or JPEGs?

Comment: updated qsn or can try your case also. Tell what should be better option to proceed

Comment: So, each image is only used once, correct? I mean `Table X Horizontal view` only appears in a single output image.

Comment: yeah exactly ..Table X Horizontal view will combine with Chair X Horizontal view

Comment: Are you able to post images of ChairY and TableX?

Comment: post means i get get path of images

Comment: So, when you combine two images that are 800x800 pixels, do you get an 800x800 pixel image as a result or a 1600x800 pixel image?

Comment: i want 800*800 just one overlapping other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with PHP's `GD` library like this:

```
<?php
$image1=imagecreatefrompng('image1.png');
$image2=imagecreatefrompng('image2.png');
$w=imagesx($image1);
$h=imagesy($image1);
imagecopy($image1,$image2,0,0,0,0,$w,$h);
imagejpeg($image1,'out.jpg');
?>
```

Or, if you want the images on a white background, you might prefer this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -f
<?php

// Read in both images
$image1=imagecreatefrompng('image1.png');
$image2=imagecreatefrompng('image2.png');

// Get their dimensions
$w=imagesx($image1);
$h=imagesy($image1);

// Now create a blank canvas on which to overlay the images
$bg=imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);

// Fill the background with white
$bgcolor=imagecolorallocate($bg,255,255,255);
imagefilledrectangle($bg,0,0,$w,$h,$bgcolor);

// Now copy the two images over the background
imagecopy($bg,$image1,0,0,0,0,$w,$h);
imagecopy($bg,$image2,0,0,0,0,$w,$h);
imagejpeg($bg,'out.jpg');
?>
```

Or you can use ImageMagick within PHP, like this:

```
<?php
   $img1=new Imagick("image1.png");
   $img2=new Imagick("image2.png");
   $img1->compositeImage($img2,imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP,0,0);
   $img1->writeImage('out.jpg'); 
?>
```

The GD version is significantly faster on my iMac, it can do 1000 iterations in 18 seconds, whereas the ImageMagick version needs 36 seconds for the same number of images.

Comment: ok thanks for the same
should i use php for that or any other language as speed is of most important

Comment: Use whatever you like! I suspect GD or ImageMagick is the way most people would go, but try anything you like.

Comment: i tried your gd solution i makes image with black backgroudn why so

Comment: There was a reason I asked (twice) for your images :-) I didn't realise you needed a white background, so I have modified the code to produce that. Please have another look.

Answer (score 3):

There are many aspects to this question and I will not pretend to cover them all. Some of the variables are:

1. The type of disk on which you store your images - mechanical disk, RAID, SSD, RAMdisk
2. The format in which you store your images - PNG, JPEG, or ImageMagick MPC for example
3. What library/software you use - GD, ImageMagick or other
4. Whether you use a multi-core/multi-threaded/distributed approach
5. How you actually implement your processing

I did some experimenting and created 1,000 images, each 512x512 pixels. I created these on a RAID, on a SSD and on a RAM disk. I created them as both PNG format and ImageMagick MPC (Magic Pixel Cache) format. Then I read them in pairwise for compositing, i.e. image0 with image999, then image1 and image998, image2 with image997 ...

The code is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm *.png *.mpc *.cache
for extension in png mpc; do
   echo Testing $extension
   # Create 1,000 input files
   for i in {0..999}; do convert -size 512x512 xc: +noise random $i.$extension ;done

   # Read the files in pairwise for processing, 0 with 999, 1 with 998, 2 with 997
   time for i in {0..999}; do j=$((999-i)) ;convert $i.$extension $j.$extension null:;done 

   rm *.png *.mpc *.cache
done
```

Here are the results for the 1,000 composites

```
RAID disk, PNG format: 43 seconds
RAID disk, MPC format: 6.9 seconds

SSD disk, PNG format: 33 seconds
SSD disk, MPC format: 6.1 seconds

RAM disk, PNG format: 30 seconds
RAM disk, MPC format: 6.0 seconds
```

I deduce there is a significant benefit to storing the images in MPC format when using ImageMagick. I also note that the RAM disk times are not much better than SSD times, so a significant amount of the processing time is probably creating the 1,000 processes to do the compositing....

... which brings me to my next point, the number of processes you create. It will probably be beneficial if you can do all the processing in a single process, so rather than do 12 processes this:

```
composite view1 with background1
composite view1 with background2
composite view2 with background1
composite view2 with background2
composite view3 with background1
composite view3 with background2
composite view4 with background1
composite view4 with background2
...
```

you should try and do this

```
load view1..4 background1..2, composite v1 b1 +write, composite v1 b2 + write, composite v1 b1  +write
```

which is easily done in ImageMagick

```
convert view{1..4} background{1..2} \( -clone 0,4 -composite +write v1b1.jpg \)
                                    \( -clone 0,5 -composite +write v1b2.jpg \)
                                    ...
```

**Note:**

Some of this answer becomes irrelevant now you have updated your question, but as I spent the time writing it, I will leave it for reference.

Comment: thanks i will also like it as its deep analysis.
can u also provide other answer based on my situation